# I showed $V$ is isomorphic to $U \times (V/U)$ without using the assumption that $V/U$ is finite-dimensional. What did I do wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, quotient-spaces

**Exercise.**

Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $V/U$ is finite-dimensional. Prove that $V$ is isomorphic to $U \times (V/U).$

---

**Outline of my proof.**

We need to construct a linear bijection between $V$ and $U \times (V/U)$, where $U \times (V/U) = \{(u, v+U) : u \in U, v \in V\}$.

I defined a mapping $T: U \times (V/U) \to V$ by

$$
T(u,v+U) = v+u
$$

where $v+u \in V$. I was then able to show the following are true about $T$:

1. Linear
2. Injective
3. Surjective

**Question.** In my full proof, I didn't use the fact that $V/U$ is finite-dimensional, which makes me think something is wrong. Is it because my $T$ is not well-defined? How come I was able to show the above three properties?

Comment: If someone would like me to provide my full proof, let me know if that will help answer the question.

Comment: How is $T$ well-defined?  (It's not.)  If $T$ isn't a function, it doesn't really mean anything to show 1-3 above.

Comment: @Randall So I'm guessing it's not well-defined? Is it because we can have $v_1 + U = v_2 + U$, but $v_1 \neq v_2$?

Comment: Yep, precisely.

Comment: @Randall got it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your "function" $T$ is not well-defined.  In particular, it is possible that $a+U = b+U$ and $a \neq b$.  In this case, you would have $T(0,a+U)=a$ and $T(0,a+U)=T(0,b+U)=b$, which is contradictory to being a function.